# OpenLayers fullTileRanges of tileGrid no longer easily available in 6.13

Tags: openlayers, javascript

Getting the details of a tileGrid was working fine in OpenLayers 6.5, but I've just upgraded to OpenLayers 6.13 and now the tileGrid keys are no longer available in plain English.  Eg, keys such as `"resolutions_"` and `"fullTileRanges_"` are not available directly in the tileGrid object.  Instead there are only the coded keys (which presumably change with each build of OpenLayers.

I'm running the following:  `layer.getSource().getTileGrid()` in order to get various details of the tileGrid in order to download tiles for a particular extent and particular zoom levels.  In 6.5 a tileGrid (logged to the console) looks like this (in part):

```
    "resolutions_" =     (
        "156543.0339279804",
        "78271.51696399009",
        "39135.75848199517",
```

whereas in 6.13, the same part looks like this:

```
    Ti =     (
        "156543.0339279804",
        "78271.51696399009",
        "39135.75848199517",
```

...and similarly for the other elements.

You may wonder why I'm accessing these properties by these keys instead of by `getResolutions()`, etc.  This is because there are some elements that don't seem to be available this way, in particular `fullTileRanges`.

I need to be able to reconstruct a tileGrid from a JSON string to use for an offline (downloaded) version of the layer like this:

`tileGrid = new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid( JSON.parse(tileGridJSON) );`

...which works fine if the `fullTileRanges` element is present, but if `fullTileRanges` is missing, then the layer that uses the tileGrid doesn't display (I think it tries to load the wrong tiles?).  So if I can't get this element from the original online tileGrid to include when saving the JSON string, then the whole thing falls over.

The following "solution" (really a work-around) works perfectly for now.  However, I consider it to be a kludge, as it uses the OpenLayers 6.13 encoded key for `fullTileRanges` ("Oo") and I expect it will break next time I upgrade my version of OpenLayers:

```
function getRasterServiceTileGrid(layerIndex) {
    var olTileGrid = rasterServiceLayers[layerIndex].getSource().getTileGrid();
    var origins = [];
    var tileSizes = [];
    var matrixIds = null;
    var fullTileRanges = null;
    if ( olTileGrid.getMatrixIds() ) {
        matrixIds = olTileGrid.getMatrixIds();
    }
    if ( olTileGrid["Oo"] ) {
        fullTileRanges = olTileGrid["Oo"];
    }
    for (var z = olTileGrid.getMinZoom(); z <= olTileGrid.getMaxZoom(); z++) {
        origins.push(olTileGrid.getOrigin(z));
        tileSizes.push(olTileGrid.getTileSize(z));
    }
    var keyedTileGrid = {
        extent: olTileGrid.getExtent(),
        maxZoom: olTileGrid.getMaxZoom(),
        minZoom: olTileGrid.getMinZoom(),
        resolutions: olTileGrid.getResolutions(),
        origins: origins,
        tileSizes: tileSizes,
        matrixIds: matrixIds,
        fullTileRanges: fullTileRanges,
    };
    
    return keyedTileGrid;
}
```

There doesn't appear to be a `tileGrid.getProperties()` function, nor a `tileGrid.get()` function, like there is for many other OL classes.

Is there a 'correct' way for me to get access to the `fullTileRanges` property in 6.13 instead of using this kludge, since I can no longer query for the "fullTileRanges_" key like I used to do with OL 6.5?

Comment: There is a undocumented `getFullTileRange` method so you could get the ranges for all zoom level using `tilegrid.getResolutions().map((r, z) => tilegrid.getFullTileRange(z))`

Comment: Hey that works!  Thanks so much.  Want to write it up as an answer?  Otherwise, I'll do so shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mike commented, there is an undocumented `getFullTileRange()` function that can be used to build up the array of all tile ranges.

I've now successfully implemented the solution as:

```
function getRasterServiceTileGrid(layerIndex) {
    var olTileGrid = rasterServiceLayers[layerIndex].getSource().getTileGrid();
    var origins = [];
    var tileSizes = [];
    var fullTileRanges = [];
    var matrixIds = null;
    if ( olTileGrid.getMatrixIds() ) {
        matrixIds = olTileGrid.getMatrixIds();
    }
    for (var z = olTileGrid.getMinZoom(); z <= olTileGrid.getMaxZoom(); z++) {
        origins.push(olTileGrid.getOrigin(z));
        tileSizes.push(olTileGrid.getTileSize(z));
        fullTileRanges.push(olTileGrid.getFullTileRange(z));
    }
    var keyedTileGrid = {
        extent: olTileGrid.getExtent(),
        maxZoom: olTileGrid.getMaxZoom(),
        minZoom: olTileGrid.getMinZoom(),
        resolutions: olTileGrid.getResolutions(),
        origins: origins,
        tileSizes: tileSizes,
        matrixIds: matrixIds,
        fullTileRanges: fullTileRanges,
    };
    
    return keyedTileGrid;
}
```

Alternatively, as @Mike commented, instead of the `for` loop, it could also be done as:

```
tilegrid.getResolutions().map((r, z) => tilegrid.getFullTileRange(z))
```

(...and similarly for the other items in the `for` loop.)